# Convert multiple rows into 1 column without pivot in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle9i, flatten

I have a large sql query which joins columns from multiple tables to give data in this format:

```
ID  CODE    Count   Action
-----------------------------
1   A       02      VIEWED
1   A       22      CLICKED
1   A       45      PRINTED
1   A       32      SCHEDULED
2   A       34      VIEWED
2   B       14      CLICKED
2   B       23      PRINTED
2   B       78      SCHEDULED
.
.
X   D       12      CLICKED
```

The value of action can be only VIEWED, CLICKED, SCHEDULED, PRINTED.
Every combination of ID, CODE has set of max 4 rows. If there is no count for action say 'CLICKED', row for that is not present

So once I have the resultset, I want to flatten it to have data in this format :

```
Id  CODE   VIEWED   CLICKED  PRINTED  SCHEDULED
-----------------------------------------------
1   A       02         11       45      32
1   B       54         57       89      45
2   B       34         14       23      78
3   G       null       null     28      20
X   D       null       12       null    null
```

My query does a lot of thing but in short it does:

```
SELECT ID,CODE, ACTION, COUNT(*) AS COUNT  
FROM MY_TABLE 
GROUP BY ID,CODE,ACTION.
```

In this one query I want to get the result set AND then flatten the rows. I cant use union-alls etc to query the DB multiple times.

Database is Oracle 9i database, so pivot function will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to use `SUM` with `CASE`, removing `ACTION` from your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT ID, 
    CODE, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ACTION = 'VIEWED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Viewed, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ACTION = 'CLICKED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Clicked, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ACTION = 'PRINTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Printed, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ACTION = 'SCHEDULED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Scheduled
FROM MY_TABLE 
GROUP BY ID,
    CODE
```

Comment: You need to sum the field `count` instead of adding 1. Like, `CASE WHEN ACTION = 'VIEWED' THEN count ELSE 0 END`

Comment: @Dba -- wasn't completely sure from the question.  OP mentions `COUNT(*)` creates the `Count` field.  Using `SUM` with `CASE` like this should yield the same result, but only summing where matching on the `Action` field. Regards.

Comment: Yes, You are right, it was very much clear from the question. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I am sorry, so  I wrap another select over the original query :SELECT ID, 
    CODE, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ACTION = 'VIEWED' THEN COUNT ELSE 0 END) Viewed FROM (SELECT ID,CODE, ACTION, COUNT(*) AS COUNT  
FROM MY_TABLE )
GROUP BY ID,CODE,ACTION ). Correct ? Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

```
 select id,code,decode(action,'VIEWED',count,'null') viewed,
                decode(action,'CLICKED',count,'null') Clicked, 
                decode(action,'PRINTED',count,'null') Printed,
                decode(action,'SCHEDULED',count,'null') Scheduled from you_table groub by ID,CODE;
```